# Home device tries to connect directly to the Internet Service Provider, bypassing the router

Tags: networking, router, internet, lan, mac-address

I have a router `ASUS RT-AC1200`. Firmware is the latest: `3.0.0.4.380_10931-gfed566f`.

It is connected to my Internet Service Provider (ISP). The router has a static MAC address, which I don't change at all. Different clients are connected to the router via LAN cable.

My ISP has filtering logic, that provides internet connection by MAC address. So the internet connection is stuck to this MAC address. When the MAC address is changed, it means a new device tries to connect to the ISP, and the ISP disconnects it and blocks the internet.
So, from time to time, I'm getting issues, that my ISP disconnects me from the internet. It happens let's say once per couple of months. I need to call them to ask them to reconnect me.

We figured out that, the reason for reconnecting was a connection from a different MAC address. Last time we checked the new MAC address, and it is my Sony Television MAC address. It's connected via LAN cable to the router.

So, how it's possible, that my internal network MAC address is exposed externally? How to disable that "feature" or fix the issue.

Comment: How did you figure out that the reason is a different MAC address? This seems impossible. Question: How is the router connected to the ISP - is there a modem between it and the ISP, or is it a modem-router in one?

Comment: Have you tried a different, good, and entirely different router?  Nothing like you have described here or in my own experience.

Comment: @harrymc When the Internet was disconnected, I called my ISP and they said that the reason was that I was trying to connect with a different MAC Address (they provided it to me) and that new MAC address was my Sony TV MAC address (I found it in TV networking configuration).

Comment: @harrymc As I understood, ISP knows my home address, they know what fiber cable is connected to me and they know my MAC address, which I suppose was provided when they connected me to the internet first time. Connection topology: Asus router -> modem -> optical fiber. So when MAC address changes, they just disconnect me from the internet.

Comment: @John I didn't try another router. I don't have steps on how to reproduce it, I don't see any patterns or preconditions. Just casual day-to-day home internet usage. It just happens from time to time, but not often, like once per couple of weeks or months. Most likely new router will help to solve the issue. But I thought maybe some configuration could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You state, "My ISP has filtering logic, that provides internet connection by MAC address." That can only be enforced on traffic **going through the router**. There is no bypassing of that router. Unless the device, such as that Sony Television, has a direct connection to the fiber-optic or copper cable going to your house from outside, it **must** communicate through the router.

Many **routers** (not ISP's) have the ability to [limit connections based on MAC ID](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mac-filtering-in-computer-network/).

Perhaps your issue is *because* your router was so restricted. If so, then add the MAC ID of each device you use to that list. For example, smart clothes washers and printers have WiFi connectivity to order supplies. If you want a device connected, add the MAC to the *router's* allowed list.

On the other hand, if your ISP is "looking over your shoulder" at the *router's* connect log, then do the opposite, and *exclude* these WiFi-enabled devices in the *router's* list (or allow all known devices, but forbid new connections, *at the router*).

Comment: Actually, it is the issue, that somehow TV was directly communicated to my ISP, bypassing the router. I know that it "must" communicate through the router, but it is what it is. ISP got a connection from the device with my TV mac address. My home network topology is the following: "TV->Cable->Router->Moden->Fiber Cable->ISP". I don't change anything, and the issue happens from time to time. That's why I'm asking how it's possible. Wether it is some specific configuration, or.. otherwise, it is a router firmware issue.